# Openerp email template location

Tags: email, templates, odoo

I'm configuring OpenERP to send invitation mails for meetings. Everything was going well until I wanted to change content. It should be available in email templates but it's not. Unfortunately only templates I can find are for invoice, sell and buy orders. As long as the mails are sent from system I was wandering where is their content loaded from. Can anyone help me find it out?

Comment: You can create your own template for meetings.

Comment: Following your suggestion I have created a new template for meetings. What placeholder should i use to fill recipients? I've tried dynamic values builder, but only mail addresses I could find were for Organizer and Partner. 

Found another issue. I've written certain values into template just to check if it's working. It's not. I've checked mails sent before using sender from meetings and they don't even have related document model assigned. What would that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `addons/base_calendar/base_calendar.py` search for html_invitation.
this is static in py file for Meeting invitation mail

Comment: That's what I've been looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@Michał : you have customized your own template which you want. OpenERP will provide you few demo templates. For meeting reminder or send invitation for meeting,You have to make a new.

Comment: Yes, i have to make a new template and that's what I'm trying to do. Firs thing is, what model am I supposed to chose: meeting or meeting invitation? Another thing is how to point recipients, because i know that From can be set as: ${object.organizer_id.user_email}. Recipients are stored in attendee_ids filed, but it seems to be assigned to separate model.